# What is the best (i.e quickest) way to find the "top 10" users in a discord server with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to add some basic stat-bot functionality to a Python discord bot. I do actually already have a way that does it very slow. I want the bot to be able to respond within 2 or 3 seconds maximum, but even in my small personal server it took a good minute just to calculate it with my code:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@is_Admin()
async def top10(ctx):
    """Prints a pretty graph of top 10 users in the server"""
    server = ctx.guild
    users = [[0 for x in range(0, len(server.members))] for x in range(0, 2)] 
    users[0] = [u.id for u in server.members]
    h = 0
    for channel in server.text_channels:
        hist = await channel.history(limit=None).flatten()
        for message in hist:
            au = message.author
            if au.bot == False:
                try:
                    i = users[0].index(au.id)
                    users[1][i] += 1
                except ValueError as e:
                    pass
```

As I said, it's *very* slow. I figure there has to be some better way to do this than getting the full history of each channel in a server and just counting up times a user made a message, but I am stumped. Anyone have any help?

Comment: You're rereading the entire history every time you want to display the top users.  Why not save the data up until now, remembering the last message you saw.  Then, the next time the command is called, you can read the history from that message to the present, and use that to modify the data structure.  A more stable solution would be to maintain a database of users and their messaging statistics.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much more optimization you can apply on your code to make it go a lot faster, since you're accessing every message ever sent in all of the text channels, even the doc stated that setting limit to `None` is a slow operation:

> [***`limit (Optional[int])`***](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#textchannel) – The number of messages to retrieve. If `None`,
>   retrieves every message in the channel. Note, however, that this would
>   make it a slow operation.

However some minor optimization can still be made, such as not creating three lists of members in the beginning and using the collections module for easy tallying.

```
from collections import Counter

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@is_Admin()
async def top10(ctx):
    top = Counter()      
    for channel in ctx.guild.text_channels:
        async for message in channel.history(limit=None):
            author = message.author
            if not author.bot:
                top[author.id] += 1
    print([x[0] for x in top.most_common(10)])
```